# Tight borders around and left-aligned text in a TikZ matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

I would like to draw SQL diagrams in TikZ using the `matrix` library. However, the following code annoyingly creates unnecessary space around the nodes in the matrices. When I then try to draw arrows between matrix nodes to display the relationships between the tables, the arrow heads end up inside the matrix borders. This is demonstrated by the following code and picture:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,matrix,calc}

\tikzset{
  -|-/.style={
    to path={
      (\tikztostart) -| ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) |- (\tikztotarget)
      \tikztonodes
    }
  },
  -|-/.default=0.5,
  |-|/.style={
    to path={
      (\tikztostart) |- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) -| (\tikztotarget)
      \tikztonodes
    }
  },
  |-|/.default=0.5,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  ->, >=stealth,
  thick,
  matstyle/.style={
      matrix of nodes,
      draw,
      nodes={draw=none, align= left, minimum width= 3cm}
    }
  ]

  \matrix (T1) [matstyle, column sep= 0pt] {
  Table 1 \\ \hline
  \ldots \\
  \ldots \\
  \ldots \\
  \ldots \\
  }; 
  \matrix (T2) [matstyle, right = of T1]{
    Table 2 \\ \hline
    \ldots \\
    \ldots \\
    \ldots \\
  };
  \draw (T1-3-1.east) to[-|-=.5] (T2-2-1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Unnecessarily wide borders.]

How could this be fixed? The borders should align with the edges of the nodes in the matrix, so the tail and head of the arrow would only touch the edge of the matrix and not pass through the border. Also, the text in the nodes needs to be left-aligned.

As a bonus, what is the de facto way of underlining the header row in a TikZ matrix? My way of doing it seems a bit clunky.

Comment: D'oh. The `inner sep` should be in the matrix settings, not the node ones. The question concerning the underlining of the header row still holds, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `matrix` is a `node`, so, it introduces an `inner sep` between borders and contents. You can fix `inner sep=0pt`, but in this case, also `inner sep` in inner nodes is `0pt`. So, you should fix it again inside `nodes` declaration.

Independently from what happens with matrix inner sep, you are drawing an arrow between inner nodes. You can avoid this undesired effect if you use `matrix` (`T1` and `T2`) as reference.

Following code solves (I hope so!) both problems:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,matrix,calc}

\tikzset{
  -|-/.style={
    to path={
      (\tikztostart) -| ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) |- (\tikztotarget)
      \tikztonodes
    }
  },
  -|-/.default=0.5,
  |-|/.style={
    to path={
      (\tikztostart) |- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) -| (\tikztotarget)
      \tikztonodes
    }
  },
  |-|/.default=0.5,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  ->, >=stealth,
  thick,
  matstyle/.style={
      matrix of nodes,
      draw,
      inner sep=0pt,
      nodes={draw=none, align= left, minimum width= 3cm, inner sep=.3333em}
    }
  ]

  \matrix (T1) [matstyle, column sep= 0pt] {
  Table 1 \\ \hline
  \ldots \\
  \ldots \\
  \ldots \\
  \ldots \\
  }; 
  \matrix (T2) [matstyle, right = of T1]{
    Table 2 \\ \hline
    \ldots \\
    \ldots \\
    \ldots \\
  };
  \draw ([yshift=-1mm]T1.east) to[-|-=.5] ([yshift=1mm]T2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]